# Sorting lambda expression for this

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a list of items which I want to sort but I can't seems to get the lambda expression right. can someone leads me to the lambda expression?
Thanks

unsorted list item:

```
number: 2, Date: 21/10/2010 11:22:55
number: 1, Date: 21/10/2010 11:22:55
number: 2, Date: 20/10/2010 12:10:00
number: 1, Date: 20/10/2010 12:10:00
```

sorted list item:

```
number: 1, Date: 21/10/2010 11:22:55
number: 1, Date: 20/10/2010 12:10:00
number: 2, Date: 21/10/2010 11:22:55
number: 2, Date: 20/10/2010 12:10:00

itemList.sort((x, y) => ...);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Linq's [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) and [`ThenByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenbydescending.aspx) extension methods:

```
using System.Linq;
...

var sortedItems = 
    itemList.OrderBy(x => x.number)
            .ThenByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

This will create a new object. If you want to assign it back to the original `itemList`, simply do this:

```
using System.Linq;
...

itemList = itemList.OrderBy(x => x.number)
                   .ThenByDescending(x => x.Date)
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: i forgot to state that the itemList datatype is List<item>. there is no orderby method in native c# list

Comment: Well no.. that's what the `System.Linq` namespace is for..

Comment: There is.. You probably need using System.Linq; as all Linq is implemented as extension methods on IEnumerable

Comment: oh I forgot to add linq namespace

Comment: @user1599647, it's an extension method.